# How to make non-interactive ssh environment same as iteractive ssh environment

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

My environment configuration is different when I execute commands using ssh string parameter (non-interactive ssh) instead of running them by hand in server (interractive ssh)?

Example: When I run `ssh <user@servername> "echo \$SGE_ROOT"`, I get empty string. When I connect to my server `ssh <user@servername>` and run command `echo $SGE_ROOT` I get `/opt/gridengine`.

I guess some kind of profile script is not executed. Is it possible to find out which script and run it through non-interactive ssh to make environment configuration identical?

Server uses CentOS 6.6.

Comment: It seems like [dublicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man). My more specific question is How to find out which scripts are not executed in non-interactive ssh?

Comment: Running ```ssh <user@servername> "source /etc/profile; echo \$SGE_ROOT" ``` worked.

Comment: please, write the solution into the answer field to help others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that none of profile or bash scripts are executed when using non-interactive ssh. So I had to call them explicitly:

```
ssh <user@servername> "source /etc/profile; echo \$SGE_ROOT"
```

Also I had to comment this line in `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```